# Login Button Element VB Script

Tags: vbscript

Trying to have a VBScript auto-login to a DVR landing page. Just trying to automate the process for our user for simplicity.

This is what I have so far, and I'm a coding novice so don't laugh too hard, still learning!

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "**********" 

Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
    Loop While IE.Busy  
    IE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = "****"
    WScript.sleep 500
    IE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = "****"
    WScript.sleep 500
    IE.Document.All.Item("login").Click
```

My problem is the login "Click". It just doesn't do anything, no matter what I try, so I know I'm just doing something wrong here. I've inspected the code from the webpage, but can't seem to figure out what element to choose to make it work!

This is a screenshot of the source for the login button on the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCxIq.jpg

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to have my code click that button! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I made a mistake in my post. If I try other things to get the button to click I get line errors, but as the code stands right now, I don't get any errors but it just doesn't click login. The username and password fill no issues, I just can't get it to click login for the life of me.